# When do Docker / ECS containers for Jenkins nodes spin up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Please read the entire question before you start to give an answer, because I have a tendency to ask long winded questions with a lot of information. Don't forget to refresh the page because I may edit the question to add additional information. I am not a native English speaker, so if you don't understand my question, please follow the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), and ask additional questions in the comments. Thank you!

---

**Executive summary**

I don't know how and when Jenkins decides to spin up a Docker instance.

---

Current infrastructure:

- Jenkins master (Linux) in local datacenter (3 executors)
- Jenkins node (Windows) in local datacenter (3 executors)
- Jenkins node (Linux) as a permanent Amazon EC2 instance (3 executors)

I have added a Docker cloud on Amazon ECS. In Jenkins I have added the Amazon EC2 Container Service plugin. I have configured it according to the screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

I have set up a simple pipeline job to test this:

```
pipeline {
   agent {
       label 'ecs'
   }

   tools {
      maven "M3"
   }

   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            // Get some code from a GitHub repository
            git 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'

            // Run Maven on a Unix agent.
            sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean package"
         }

         post {
            // If Maven was able to run the tests, even if some of the test
            // failed, record the test results and archive the jar file.
            success {
               junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
               archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar'
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is the demo pipeline that comes with Jenkins, the only change I made was to replace

```
   agent any
```

with

```
   agent {
       label 'ecs'
   }
```

When I run this job, I can see in the console log that a Docker instance is being spun up, which takes maybe less than half a minute, and then the build runs. After a couple of minutes, the Docker instance is gone again.

I know that the `ecs-cloud` is being spun up because I have an agent template with a label `ecs` and I have a job with label `ecs` so I'm forcing that job to run on that node only. So far so good. This proves to me that on the Amazon side, everything is basically set up as it is supposed to be.

I have many, many jobs that run on `agent any`, so I would *expect* that once all executors on `master`, the Windows node, and the permanent EC2 node are saturated, that the `ecs-cloud` kicks in. However, the *actual* result is that I cannot predict when that happens. When I'm watching Jenkins, I see all static executors get saturated, the build queue fills up, and no `ecs-cloud` in sight. But then I log off and when I look at the logs the next day, I see that some jobs *have* run on `ecs-cloud` overnight. It's almost as if they want to hide from me. Only when I run that test job mentioned above, which explicitly runs on `ecs-cloud`, and I wait for it to finish but the `ecs-cloud` hasn't cleaned up after itself yet, only then I can reliably say when other jobs will also run on `ecs-cloud`.

*Now comes my question.*

How can I, in a reliable and predictable way, determine when a Jenkins job will spin up a Docker container on `ecs-cloud`?

Comment: I would say, this is Jenkins inbuilt algorithm to place the jobs on the slaves. As you mentioned `any`, then it can pickup any available slavem until/unless you are not forcing to run it on particular Slave.

Comment: That... doesn't really answer my question in a satisfying way.

Comment: Probably, worth looking at the Jenkins scheduler - https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/even-scheduler

Comment: You have linked to the documentation of a commercial plugin. However, it appears that we have the https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/ plugin installed, which claims to have the same functionality as the commercial plugin. I have uninstalled it, I'll evaluate the result and post back the results.